# Forcing the copy constructor instead of the move constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

My program crashes then a string objects gets deleted, I suppose because I use oracle library compiled for VS 2010, while I'm using VS 2015. Here is the line where it crashes:

```
string f1 = cObj.getString(MetaData::ATTR_NAME);
```

I get a normal string, I can use it, but when it goes out of scope it crashes trying to deallocate.
Now, when reading about using older version DLL, I read that we should always leave the deallocation of memory to the DLL if the allocation happens inside that library. What I suppose happens here is that the move constructor get's called, so at the end it tries to deallocate the string having memory allocated by the oracle dll.

So my question is, is there a way to explicitly call the copy constructor of the string in this case?

Comment: Possible CRT mismatch

Comment: Does it work if you use assignment explicitly? If not your problem might sit elsewhere.

Comment: You can force the copy constructor with `string f1 = const_cast<const string &>(cObj.getString(MetaData::ATTR_NAME);` but I doubt that fixes your version mismatch.

Comment: @nwp, strange, now deallocate get's called right after your line and the program crashes, so it means there is temporary object being destroyed - meaning that the problem may not be in move constructor ? It doesn't happen for all these function calls, so it's kind of hard to understand this CRT stuff...

Comment: You should explain exactly what you mean by "My program crashes". It's hard to diagnose otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I would try to find a VS2015 version of the dll. If that is unavailable you can install VS2010 and select the VS2010 kit in VS2015. If that is also not viable write a wrapper in VS2010 that exposes the DLL functions through sockets or a pipe. Some bad possibilities are to just not use functions returning objects with dynamic memory or to leak their memory.

Comment: @nwp  Thanks, I already have vs 2010, was trying to port my project to VS2010, changed the toolkit to 2010 inside VS2015, and it works fine, guess it was really a CRT problem. Thanks :) You could make an answer based on your two comments, they answered my question, even though I don't understand why these CRT problems appear so randomly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable and the linked DLL must be binary compatible. Generally they need to have been produced by the same compiler. Sometimes different compiler versions use the same [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and it keeps working, but not in your case.

The ABI defines among other things how to allocate and free memory and the DLL and executable have different assumptions on how that works and therefore crash.

There are different ways to fix that problem, sorted from good to bad:

1. Make the versions agree by upgrading the DLL
2. Make the versions agree by downgrading the executable
3. Write a wrapper in the correct version to expose the functionality through a socket or pipe
4. Do not use functions that return objects with dynamic memory
5. Leak the memory

In case of Visual Studio you can install the old and the new version of Visual Studio, go to `Solution Explorer`, `Configuration Properties`, `General`, `Platform Toolset` and [select the old platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx) in the new version.

Note that downgrading the target platform makes new functions unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer :)